# Prepration of a Gaussian modulated coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, coherent-states

In Continuous Variable -Quantum Key Distribution (CVQKD), usually Gaussian modulated coherent states are sent. This means both quadratures of a coherent state are chosen from two normal distribution. So do we can prepare a state with well-known quadratures on the phase space? My main question is, how someone can successfully create a coherent state with exactly well-known phase and amplitude quadratures.  I think even if experimental devices are perfect, he/she can not make a quantum state with exact known quadratures. I think making quantum coherent states is limited by the Heisenberg uncertainty. Am  I right? In other words, do  these uncertainties  happened not only  during measurement but also during state preparation?
Sorry if my question is simple but I really need to learn it.